# Creating a normal array where one position can hold multiple values

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an array where by one position on the array needs to have two values, yet every other position has a single value.

For example:

```
Public int[] Array = new int[10];
for (int i = 1; i <11; i++)
{
   array[i] = 1
   if (i = 1)
     {
       array[i] also = 2
     }
}
```

In short I want to have the following:

```
[0] 0

[1] 1 2

[2] 1

[3] 1
```

etc

Comment: Index out of bounds exception? Arrays start at index 0, not index 1. You'd do well to update your loop `for (int i = 1; i <11; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)`

Comment: You can use `List<int>[]` or jagged array `int[][]`, or `List<List<int>>`

Comment: Integer cannot hold two integer values. If your values are limited to a known small subset, e.g. `1..5`, consider adding `6` there to indicate `1 and 2` case.

Comment: Does it _need_ to be an array? Why not a list of lists? Explain your use case: _why_ do you need _"a collection that can hold multiple values per index"_ and why do you think an int array is the appropriate data type for that? If you can explain why you need this, and what you'll do with the array afterwards, it can help very much to give you a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: What's exactly the problem you need to solve? Do the values have semantics? Are the values limited to some kind of range, other the full Int32 spectrum?

Comment: Exactly @CodeCaster, this sounds like your typical XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There is too many good answers and that's why i voted to close the question as 'too broad', please narrow it so it'd be easier to understand what exactly you try to achieve.

Comment: Do you need to use an array ? If not I would suggest something like List<Tuple<int,int>> or a List<YourClassThatManagesMultipleIntegerValues>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a jagged array

```
public int[][] array = new int[10][];
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
   if (i==1)
    array[i] = new int[2];
   else
    array[i] = new int[1];
   array[i][0] = (i==0) ? 0 : 1
   if (i = 1)
   {
     array[i][1] = 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multi-dimensional arrays, like so

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] array = new int[10, 10];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length / 10; i++)
    {
        array[i, 0] = 1;
        if(i == 1)
        {
            array[i, 1] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

**[0, 0] = 1**
[0, 1] = 0 ... [0, 9] = 0
**[1, 0] = 1

[1, 1] = 2**
[1, 2] = 0 ... [1, 9] = 0
**[2, 0] = 1**
[2, 1] = 0 ... [2, 9] = 0
**[3, 0] = 1**
[3, 1] = 0 ... [3, 9] = 0
**[4, 0] = 1**
[4, 1] = 0 ... [4, 9] = 0
**[5, 0] = 1**
[5, 1] = 0 ... [5, 9] = 0
**[6, 0] = 1**
[6, 1] = 0 ... [6, 9] = 0
**[7, 0] = 1**
[7, 1] = 0 ... [7, 9] = 0
**[8, 0] = 1**
[8, 1] = 0 ... [8, 9] = 0
**[9, 0] = 1**
[9, 1] = 0 ... [9, 9] = 0

Comment: Yeah you can, but now you have 9 unused elements and when iterating over the elements, no way to detect whether a value of `0` was intended, or that it denotes the end of a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the question why you need this, you could go like this:

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot the second implicit conversion to use the IntWithSideValue directly...

```
public struct IntWithSideValue {
    public int Int1;
    public int? Int2;

    public IntWithSideValue(int i1)
        : this(i1, null) { }
    public IntWithSideValue(int i1, int? i2) {
        Int1 = i1;
        Int2 = i2;
    }
    //this will transform a "normal" int directly into this struct
    public static implicit operator IntWithSideValue(int IntValue) {
        return new IntWithSideValue(IntValue, null);
    }
    //This will return Int1 if you use this "directly" like an "normal" int...
    //If you'd rather use Int2 (in case of existence), use ??-operator like Int2 ?? Int1
    public static implicit operator int(IntWithSideValue iwsv) {
        return iwsv.Int1;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
        var MyArray=new IntWithSideValue[5];
        MyArray[0] = new IntWithSideValue(0,null);
        MyArray[1] = new IntWithSideValue(1);
        MyArray[2] = 2;
        MyArray[3] = new IntWithSideValue(3, 10);
        MyArray[4] = 4;

        var sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Index {0}, Int1 {1} Int2 {2} Behaves like int (+3): {3}",
                          i, MyArray[i].Int1, MyArray[i].Int2, 
                          MyArray[i] + 3)); //direct usage
        }
        var result = sb.ToString();
```

Will produce this result:

```
Index 0, Int1 0 Int2     Behaves like int (+3): 3
Index 1, Int1 1 Int2     Behaves like int (+3): 4
Index 2, Int1 2 Int2     Behaves like int (+3): 5
Index 3, Int1 3 Int2 10  Behaves like int (+3): 6
Index 4, Int1 4 Int2     Behaves like int (+3): 7
```